# Encapsulate complexity in table variables is a best practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, refactoring

Sometimes I need to refactor some huge monster query in which i identify some repetitions.

The final result is something, not perfect, but like this (here i oversimplify for the sake of communicating):

```
DECLARE @CustomersEligibleForDiscount TABLE
(
CustomerID int,
Rate int
)

insert into @CustomersEligibleForDiscount
SELECT STATEMENT to populate table variable

DECLARE @ActiveCampaigns TABLE
(
CampaignID int,
Expiration date,
Prize decimal(4,2)
)

insert into @ActiveCampaigns
SELECT STATEMENT to populate table variable


DECLARE @OneOfTheManyOhterTables TABLE
(
TABLE DEFINIION
)
insert into @OneOfTheManyOhterTables
SELECT STATEMENT to populate table variable

-- GIven the table variables above i can write the main query in this was

SELECT
 FIELDS
FROM @CustomersEligibleForDiscount CEFD
JOIN @@OneOfTheManyOhterTables OT ON ...
[...]
JOIN @ActiveCampaigns ON...

-- In this way the main query is much more readable

-- THen since those table variables contain the "business logic" it happens that i need to use them
-- in stored function that return tables so i redeclare all the variables (may be i just need a subset)
-- in the stored function again, example:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.sf_GiveMeATable(@CustomerID int,@LastLogin DATETIME)
RETURNS @ResultsTAble TABLE
(
    ID int,
    CODE nvarchar(50),
    DESCR nvarchar(120)
)

BEGIN

  DECLARE @CustomersEligibleForDiscount TABLE
  (
  CustomerID int,
  Rate int 
  )
  insert into @CustomersEligibleForDiscount
  SELECT STATEMENT to populate table variable

  DECLARE @OneOfTheManyOhterTables TABLE
  (
  TABLE DEFINIION  
  )
  insert into @OneOfTheManyOhterTables
  SELECT STATEMENT to populate table variable

  DO SOMETHING TO POPULATE @ResultsTAble
  RETURN

END
```

In this example I completely ignore indexes and performance (that must be of course considered), because i want to focus on the approach.

For sure readibiity is improved, but i am not sure this is a best practice or jsut something i figured out on a rainy day.

My question is: is this approach considered a best pratice when it comes to refactor complex queries written by others and you do not have total control on db schema?

Comment: using table variables could hardly be called best practice given their limitations! (although better in SQL 2017)  Your bigger concern should be not using multi-statement TVFs....

Comment: Repetition is not necessarily bad. If you are not solving any problem or intentionally improving performance, then you are only creating work and risk by doing this. One should not be randomly picking **working** code that "one does not like" in order to "improve" it in some undefined and unmeasured manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this considered a best pratice when it comes to refactor
>   complex queries written by others and you do not have total control on
>   db schema?

Using Table Variables or Temporary Tables to spool intermediate results in a complex query is a very common pattern in SQL Server.  Temporary Tables are probably preferred as they have better support for indexes and statistics.

It's not a "best practice" in the sense that you should always or normally do it.  The basic pattern is to use Common Table Expressions to logically separate subqueries and turn the complex query into a logical "pipeline" of transformations.  If you discover that the query is too complex, or that the query plan is not to your liking, then running one or more of the subqueries ahead of time and loading a temp table or table variable is a common approach.

In TSQL a Table Valued Function can be used to encapsulate a query, and like the choice between a CTE (or subquery) and a temp table, you can choose whether the TVF's is just a way to reuse a query expression, or is executed separately from the enclosing query.  A Multi-Statement Tabled Value Function will get its own execution plan, while an Inline Table-Valued Function will be integrated into the query plan of the enclosing query.

So of the ways to encapsulate a query, some integrate the query expression into the containing query before it is optimized:

- CTE's and Subqueries
- Inline Table-Valued Functions
- Views

And some separate the execution of the query and integrate the *results* into the larger query:

- Queries loading Temp Tables or Table Variables
- Multi-Statement Table Valued Functions

Comment: my concern is also about reusing (copy and paste) the table variables in the definition of t TVF.